# How to iterate over a list of words in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
input="usr/share/dict/words"
while IFS= read -r line
do
     if [[ ${line:0:1} == "a" ]]
          then
          key="$(openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac '$line' whiskey.jpg)"
          if [[ $key == "G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292" ]]
               then
               echo "$line"
          fi
     fi
done < "$input"
```

This is what I have so far for a class I'm in. The instructions are to write a short Bash script that reads through a list of words line-by-line, filters out any not beginning with the letter 'a', then runs to see if the out for any given word matches the desired digest we are given for the image whiskey.jpg as one of the words is the key for it.

The comparison statements for filtering words beginning with 'a' functions properly and prints them out, however I've never worked on a bash script in the past so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in trying to run each line/word through to find a matching output. Right now it seems to indefinitely until I quit it, with no visible output.

Comment: If you're told to use the `shasum` command, why do you use `openssl` instead? I also didn't understand what the shasum of a word has to do with the shasum of an image file. Are you supposed to shasum the filename or the file contents?

Comment: Does it actually run forever, or just slowly? Especially if the file's big, it'll take a little while to compute each hash, so repeating that a large number of times could take a while. Suggestion: add `else echo "Nope, $line isn't it"` to the inner test, so you see each trial as it happens.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your Bash issue, but: you're misusing the terms "key" and "digest". The "key" here is the dictionary word (= the line); `G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292` is an "HMAC".

Comment: Wrong title: `Write me a bruteforce script` is more appropriate...

Comment: You can simplify `[[ ${line:0:1} == "a" ]]` -> `[[ $line == a* ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. In order, starting with the second line:

```
input="usr/share/dict/words"
```

Since this path doesn't start with "/", it'll be treated as relative to the current directory. Add a "/" to the front. Next:

```
key="$(openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac '$line' whiskey.jpg)"
```

Here, the single-quotes around `'$line'` prevent the variable from being expanded (it's just treated as a literal string). Use double-quotes instead. Note that normally quotes don't nest -- that is, there's no such thing as a double-quoted string inside another double-quoted string -- but in this case `$( )` creates a new quoting context, so the nesting works.  Next:

```
if [[ $key == "G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292" ]]
```

The shell syntax is fine here, the problem is that `$key` will be something like "HMAC-SHA1(whiskey.jpg)= G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292", and the comparison string only matches the end of that. But inside `[[ ]]`, the `==` operator can do wildcard comparison, so add a wildcard: `if [[ $key == *"G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292" ]]`

Finally, the script doesn't exit after finding a match, it'll search through the rest of the words file looking for more matches. So add `exit` after the `echo` when it finds a match.

Here's the result of these fixes:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/usr/share/dict/words"
while IFS= read -r line
do
     if [[ ${line:0:1} == "a" ]]
          then
          key="$(openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "$line" whiskey.jpg)"
          if [[ $key == *"G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292" ]]
               then
               echo "$line"
               exit
          fi
     fi
done < "$input"
```

BTW, useful troubleshooting techniques for scripts: have [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) scan your script for common mistakes (it spots the single-quote issue here), and put `set -x` before the section that isn't working, so the shell will print what it thinks is going on as the script runs. You'll see things like:

```
++ openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac '$line' whiskey.jpg
+ key='HMAC-SHA1(whiskey.jpg)= G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292'
+ [[ HMAC-SHA1(whiskey.jpg)= G11a600a8dad2Gb98f18cefec4315a6c92777292 == \G\1\1\a\6\0\0\a\8\d\a\d\2\G\b\9\8\f\1\8\c\e\f\e\c\4\3\1\5\a\6\c\9\2\7\7\7\2\9\2 ]]
```

The quoting/escaping looks a bit weird, but you can see that `$line` isn't getting expanded, and that `$key` contains "HMAC-SHA1(whiskey.jpg)= " along with the hash.